# Heat equation, confusion about use of Leibniz's rule with Fundamental Theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

So I am trying to derive the heat equation and I have the following equation

$$-\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_{x}^{x+\Delta x } \frac{d}{dt} \phi(x,t)dx = u_t(x,t)$$ 
$$\phi(x,t)=-K\frac{du}{dx}$$ where K is a constant and $u_{xx}$ is $\frac{d}{dx}\phi(x,t)$

Now my issue is understanding what happens when you take the limit as $\Delta x$ approaches zero. Does the fundamental theorem say that the left-hand side becomes $\frac{d}{dx} \phi(x,t)$ or what? I'm very confused as to how to get to the $u_{xx}$ form of the left-hand side.

Comment: well, to start, what variable are you integrating in?

Comment: Edited to include dx, sorry!

Comment: And where is any reference to $u$ in your post? What are $\phi$ and $\epsilon$ and how do they relate to $\phi$? In any event, $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_x^{x+\Delta x}\frac{d}{dt} \phi(y,t)dy=-\frac{d}{dt} \phi(x,t)$

Comment: Okay did some more edits.

Comment: This does not make sense, you can not have $dx$ in integral and also $x$ as upper and lower limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is just a **hint**. Consider $$g(x_0) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_0}f(x)dx$$
Now we can verify that we will get:
$$\frac{g(x_0+\Delta x) - g(x_0)}{\Delta x} = \frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_{x_0}^{x_0+\Delta x}f(x)dx$$

Do you recognize the expression to the left? What happens when you take the considered limit on it?

Comment: Oh my god of course!! Thank you!